# Android - png image creating a white patch

Tags: android, button, drawing, png, drawable

I have a .png file , which when I put on a button, it gives a white patch instead of the transparent background.

Iam using

```
btn6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f);
```

This puts the png on the button, but the areas excluding the image are patched as white. What to do?

Comment: Maybe image not transparent? post image of the what you get and image that you try to put on that button

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an ImageButton.

Try to set the background of ImageButton in XML file to @null

android:background="@null"

And in your code try to set imageResource instead of background.

btn6.setImageResource(R.drawable.f);

**Edit :** 
Sikp Xml edits and do
btn6.setImageResource(R.drawable.f);
btn6.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

Comment: I can do that, but that will remove the gray button that I have to start with....what do i do?

Comment: @i need to set the background on some action

Comment: Along with btn6.setImageResource(R.drabable.f); set btn6.setBackgroundDrawable(null); in your action to remove the background and setting the image source.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a transparent background png file.
you should use PhotoShop to remove the white patch